# excel function "search of the decision function in R

Tags: r

I have the question, whether it is possible in R to implement an excel function "search of the decision"? Is there function in R or it is necessary to create a script in R.
It is necessary to solve the following equation by combining the `X` values to get 1,126 as the result.

```
1.126 = X / (X + 0.2) * (EXP (X + 0.2) -1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the solution to this equation using `uniroot`. The solution to your equation is the same as the solution to `X / (X + 0.2) * (exp(X + 0.2) -1) - 1.126 = 0`   So ...

```
Dec = function(X) X / (X + 0.2) * (exp(X + 0.2) - 1) - 1.126
uniroot(Dec, c(0,2))
```

(part of) the result is

> $root [1]
>   0.6959234
>   $f.root [1]
>   -1.585758e-06

If you need more accuracy,  you can adjust the `tol` parameter.

```
uniroot(Dec, c(0,2), tol= 0.0000001)
```

> $root
>   [1]  0.6959241
>   $f.root
>   [1] 7.61391e-13