# excel function "search of the decision function in R, but for two or more unknowns

Tags: r

In this post [excel function "search of the decision function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52456386/excel-function-search-of-the-decision-function-in-r/52456462#52456462), G5W provided good solution, but it is equation with one unknown member(X)
What about if we have deal with two  unknowns?
example

```
3x - 5y = 2
```

How to search  the decision"? It is necessary to solve the following equation by combining the `x` and `y` values to get 2 as the result.
(at manual calculation in this simple equation x=4 and y=2)

or if we have a deal with three unknowns
something like this
[image]

As a rule, such equations can have an infinite number of solutions, how to derive not more than three of them?

How `uniroot` function adapt for such equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is linear equations, `solve` can do it.

```
lhs <- matrix(c(3, -2, 5,
                7, 4, -8,
                5, -3, -4), nrow=3, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
rhs <- c(7, 3, -12)
sol <- solve(lhs, rhs)
sol
# [1] 1 3 2

3*sol[1] -2*sol[2] + 5*sol[3]
#[1] 7
```

For non-linear equation, there are libraries such as `nleqslv`, `rootSolve`, `BB`.
For example,

```
fun <- function(x) {
  lhs %*% x - rhs
}

library(nleqslv)
nleqslv(c(1, 1, 1), fun)
# $x
# [1] 1 3 2
# 
# $fvec
# [1] -1.776357e-15  0.000000e+00 -3.552714e-15
# 
# $termcd
# [1] 1
# 
# $message
# [1] "Function criterion near zero"
# 
# $scalex
# [1] 1 1 1
# 
# $nfcnt
# [1] 1
# 
# $njcnt
# [1] 1
# 
# $iter
# [1] 1
```

`fun` can be a nonlinear function.

Comment: You beat me by a few seconds. And your answer is more complete, I wasn't posting anything nonlinear.